# XPages bootstrap css not applied to dynamically generated items

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, xpages

We have recently started adding bootstrap to our application and struggling with some basics I believe.

So, well we had a tradition extension library "dropDownButton" on our page which worked precisely well, however, for bootstrap, we are using the normal html list menu as suggested on bootstrap website, all works well here, except when the menu is generated dynamically. Please see the code below:

```
<div class="btn-group" role="group">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
 Menu
 <span class="caret"></span>
 </button>
 <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li class="dropdown-submenu"><a href="#">New</a>
         <ul class="dropdown-menu">
             <li class="dropdown-submenu"><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Document</a>
                 <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                 <xp:repeat id="repeat1" rows="30" var="documentName"
                    indexVar="documentIndex">
                    <xp:this.value>
                      <![CDATA[#{javascript: //some processing; return z;}]]>
                    </xp:this.value>
                    <xp:text tagName="li" escape="false" styleClass="red">
                       <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:
                       return '<a>' + documentName + '</a>';}]]></xp:this.value>
                     </xp:text>
                  </xp:repeat>
            </ul>
       </li> 
     </ul>  
     </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

In the above code everything displays well, except the things generated dynamically in the repeat control. Viewing the source code everything is generated perfectly, so, what we believe here is that css is not applied to the elements generated dynamically. Now this shouldn't be the case normally (normally css should be applied) but I am not sure what can we wrong here.

Any help would really be appreciated.

Note: We are not using Bootstrap4Xpages as of now ( we have just added the bootstrap specific libraries.

Comment: Looking at http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns there is a <div> around the whole construct. Did you implement it, too? And please check the version you are using with your implemented libs. The documentation refers to the latest version and HTML implementation differs from older versions.

Comment: Yea, I just copy pasted part of my entire code, so missed to copy the div element..just added..anyways I am using the latest version. As mentioned in the question, if I write it down statically it works fine, it just doesn't work with the repeat control (dynamically), so I believe nothing wrong with the css implementation here..please correct me if I am wrong..

Comment: CSS *is* applied so something else is wrong. I suspect an extra div from the repeat. Show us the generated HTML. Also try working with repeat properties such as setting removeRepeat to true.

Comment: So, finally found the problem, it was with the "ID" attribute of repeat control, just add the id and it breaks down the css. I have created the answer, so could be useful for others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, FINALLY there were 2 problems:

1. ID attribute with the repeat control: Somehow any id attribute given to repeat control breaks down the css (probably because of dynamic id generation in XPages?)
2. Stwissel's Answer: It is necessary somehow to add role and other attributes as mentioned in the boostrap's documentation (and stwissel's answer) for proper css.

Just to show the corrected answer (only repeat loop)

```
<!-- I have just removed the id="repeat1" -->
<xp:repeat rows="30" var="documentName"
                    indexVar="documentIndex"> 
                    <xp:this.value>
                      <![CDATA[#{javascript: //some processing; return z;}]]>
                    </xp:this.value>
                    <xp:text tagName="li" escape="false" role="presentation">
                       <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:
                       return '<a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">' + documentName + '</a>';}]]></xp:this.value>
                     </xp:text>
</xp:repeat>
```

Thanks a lot for all the help, otherwise wouldn't have got this answer.

Answer (score 1):

when you check the documentation, the example says:

```
<li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Action</a></li>
```

Your code above does neither generate the role for the li element nor the role for the anchor element. AFAIK You need to reorder your code to include these attributes.

Comment: I will try adding it when I am back in office. Thanks. However, logically, it shouldn't work in the normal case too (which it is now), that is something strange..!

Comment: So, finally found the problem, it was with the "ID" attribute of repeat control, just add the id and it breaks down the css.

Answer (score 1):

I just tested the code from the BS documentation with a repeat and it works well:

```
<div
                        class="dropdown">
                        <button
                            class="btn btn-sm btn-default dropdown-toggle"
                            type="button"
                            id="dropdownMenu1"
                            data-toggle="dropdown"
                            aria-expanded="true">
                            Dropdown
                            <span
                                class="caret"></span>
                        </button>
                        <ul
                            class="dropdown-menu"
                            role="menu"
                            aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
                            <xp:repeat
                                var="documentName">
                                <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:return ["Action 1", "Action 2", "Action 3"]}]]></xp:this.value>
                                <li
                                    role="presentation">
                                    <a
                                        role="menuitem"
                                        tabindex="-1"
                                        href="#">
                                        <xp:text
                                            value="#{documentName}"></xp:text>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </xp:repeat>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
```

I see you are using another UL within the dropdown container - that's not right refering to the documentation of version 3.2/3.3.
See a live demo of it here: http://www.notesx.net/bs3template.nsf/samples.xsp

Comment: So, finally found the problem, it was with the "ID" attribute of repeat control, just add the id and it breaks down the css.